# Securing each Content Item in Orchard CMS

Tags: authentication, authorization, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

crosspost: https://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/542161

I understand that you can lock/secure Content Types via User Roles, but I'd like to provide an option to secure each Content Item instead.

My approach is to create a custom part (let's call it SecureContentPart) which has a boolean value (ideally a checkbox in Editor/Admin). I'll attach the part to types which I want to provide the option to scure. In the part's driver, I check the value of the boolean and if the user is authenticated. If the user is unauthenticated (anonymous) and the boolean is true (item is locked), I will throw an OrchardSecurityException which basically routes it to the login/unathenticated page.

A few questions:

1. Firstly, is this the appropriate approach?
2. Is RequestContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated the best way to verify is the current user is authenticated?
3. If I define the custom part in an auth module, while attaching the part is executed in the content type's respective modules (event CT in the events module), how do I know which one runs first? (i.e. attaching the part may occur before the part is defined if they are on separate modules) Is it more appropriate to define part attachments to Content Types all in the auth module? (wanna make these as decoupled as possible)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There already is a feature in Orchard to secure individual content items. It's called `Content Item Permissions`.

Comment: appreciate the speedy reply! Apart from enabling the module, we neeed to attach the ContentPermissionsPart to each Content Type we want to secure, correct?

Comment: The editor view seems a little complicated for content editors imo. I understand the role granularity in some scenarios, but for my case I'd ideally prefer a checkbox that just locks the content item from unauthenticated users. Is it possible to set default values of the what's ticked upon attachment of the part to each type? That way the user just needs to tick the "Enable Content Item access control" field and disregard the check-boxes underneath unless further customization is needed.

Comment: Also, I tried attaching the part onto a Content Type (event in this case) which is being displayed on a projection widget within a Page. The Page allows anonymous access but the Event Item does not, however it still renders the page. Is it possible to not render it because an Event Item within that projection is not allowed for anonymous access?

Comment: Same case with the blog module. If a blog post is "secured", it is still displayed in the list of blog posts under a blog. If you secure a blog, the navigation item for that blog is not displayed.

Comment: I think only the details views checks those permissions. There's been talk of a projection filter for permissions that would do the trimming, but I'm not sure it's been written.
I any case, I was also suggesting this module as a base for building your own, simpler module.

Comment: Appreciate all the replies @Bretrand. If I wanted to do something simpler (disregard roles and just validate if authenticated or not), is my initial approach above viable? or not recommended? thanks!